# Why did Hawkeye get the Soul Stone?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Soul Stone demanded a sacrifice. Hawkeye might have truly loved Black Widow, but he didn't sacrifice her.

Black Widow actually

> committed suicide and Hawkeye tried to protect her till the end.

Hawkeye clearly fails the eligibility criteria.

Why did Hawkeye get the Soul Stone? Is this a plot hole?

Comment: Because Natasha sacrificed *herself*.

Comment: “Hawkeye clearly fails the eligibility criteria.” Oh yes: those specific, detailed eligibility criteria that we all see written down during the movie.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, she was eligible to get the Soul Stone (if she loved her life), but then she was already dead. My question: How did Hawkeye become eligible?

Comment: @Beebo  - It's only the instruction to Thanos (who brought a potential sacrifice) that a sacrifice would be required.

Comment: [Question on Movies where I answered it](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100520/45378).

Comment: I feel like maybe the instructions weren't clearly delineated on paper, and maybe we technically don't have the original source who gave them, but it's all we're given as viewers. And, since it's debatable whether Hawk's actions are an actual sacrifice, I'd say this at least deserves a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instructions that Red Skull gives to the various protagonists are different and tailored for his individual quests. In Infinity War he [tells Thanos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-699mZ1yc3g) that

> **The stone demands a sacrifice**. ... In order to take the stone, you must lose that which you love. A soul for a soul

Whereas [the instruction](https://youtu.be/EyCeSo09xOk?t=94) for Clint and Natasha in Endgame is different and makes no mention of a sacrifice being required, only that one of them has to stay (and die) for the other to get the stone.

> In order to take the stone, you must lose that which you love, **an everlasting exchange**, a soul for a soul.

It would appear that the key element of getting the stone is the losing of someone that is beloved (of the individual who'll then receive the stone) rather than the act of sacrifice. That only applies to Thanos because he brought a potential sacrifice.

---

Interestingly, the [original script](https://disneystudiosawards.s3.amazonaws.com/avengers-endgame/Avengers_Endgame.pdf) ***does*** make mention of a sacrifice but it doesn't indicate who has to make it, implying that you can sacrifice yourself for the other person.

> **NATASHA:** *The Stone is down there?*
>   RED SKULL: *For one of you. For the other...* (smiling it away) *The Stone demands a sacrifice. In order to take it, you must leave behind that which you love.*
>   [SKULL POINTS A BONY FINGER DOWN THE WELL.]
>   *A soul for a soul.*

This would imply that Natasha killing *herself* was sufficient sacrifice to meet the requirement, even if it wasn't directly mentioned.

Comment: I don’t see a conflict, there was a sacrifice and Clint does lose what he loves. The instructions make no mention that you must do so willingly or you must sacrifice the thing yourself.

Comment: Also note that the official Emmys script includes Red Skull saying _”For one of you. For the other... The Stone demands a sacrifice. In order to take it, you must leave behind that which you love.”_

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - An excellent catch. I've added it in because it bolsters my theory that self-sacrifice counts.